# Unable to get loginForm after addSiteAccount to update credentials

Tags: yodlee

I am using the rest api. After retrieving the login form for a site, I input incorrect login information. I need to now go back and correct the mistake. At first I tried calling GetSiteLoginForm, which isn't allowed since the user is already associated to the site. I then tried to SiteTraversal/getSiteInfo with valid cobSessionToken and &siteFilter.reqSpecfier=16&siteFilter.siteId=643.

The response I get is:

{"popularity":0,"siteId":643,"orgId":520,"defaultDisplayName":"Chase (US)","defaultOrgDisplayName":"Chase Manhattan Bank","contentServiceInfos":[{"contentServiceId":663,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"bank","assetType":1}},{"contentServiceId":10441,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"bill_payment","assetType":0}},{"contentServiceId":3163,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":3483,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1}},{"contentServiceId":7100,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"loans","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":3861,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"mortgage","assetType":2}},{"contentServiceId":12049,"siteId":643,"containerInfo":{"containerName":"miles","assetType":0}}],"enabledContainers":[{"containerName":"bank","assetType":1},{"containerName":"bill_payment","assetType":0},{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2},{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1},{"containerName":"loans","assetType":2},{"containerName":"mortgage","assetType":2},{"containerName":"miles","assetType":0}],"baseUrl":"http://www.chase.com/","loginForms":[],"isHeld":false,"isCustom":false,"siteSearchVisibility":true}

Note loginForms is empty. How do I get this value? I tried different values of siteFilter.reqSpecfier and always get the same result. Other things I tried were using both the our public and private urls. I duplicated all of this with Dag Site as well.

Comment: I'd say this could benefit from a little more detail.

Comment: I've provided what I sent, the url, and the response. Can't think of what else to provide. What else do you need?

Comment: Your question only contains what you get as a response. Not how you construct your query nor the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo in one of the input parameters because of which the parameter is not being recognized by our API’s and hence returning `Null` LoginForms.

```
[ siteFilter.reqSpecifier is incorrectly spelled as siteFilter.reqSpecfier ]
```

Your Excerpt from below email:

```
cobSessionToken=11182013_0%3A8e8a9caa264e3b26f15c3c9a3ee05680b2edb76272d0a425852a803e6002383b89847d388de38394b4f08efbb881536b496e323ee4e42c9df7dfdcdc8ae10e16&siteFilter.**reqSpecfier**=16&siteFilter.siteId=643
```

This should be :

```
cobSessionToken=11182013_0%3A8e8a9caa264e3b26f15c3c9a3ee05680b2edb76272d0a425852a803e6002383b89847d388de38394b4f08efbb881536b496e323ee4e42c9df7dfdcdc8ae10e16&siteFilter.**reqSpecifier**=16&siteFilter.siteId=643
```

With corrected parameter I was able to query Site 643 and get the loginForm Array. Below is the response with loginForms[]

```
{"popularity":0
"siteId":643
"orgId":520
"defaultDisplayName":"Chase"
"defaultOrgDisplayName":"Chase Manhattan Bank"
"contentServiceInfos":[{"contentServiceId":663}
{"contentServiceId":10441}
{"contentServiceId":3163}
{"contentServiceId":3483}
{"contentServiceId":7100}
{"contentServiceId":3861}
{"contentServiceId":12049}]
"enabledContainers":[{
"containerName":"bank","assetType":1}
{"containerName":"bill_payment","assetType":0}
{"containerName":"credits","assetType":2}
{"containerName":"stocks","assetType":1}
{"containerName":"loans","assetType":2}
{"containerName":"mortgage","assetType":2}
{"containerName":"miles","assetType":0}]
"baseUrl":"http://www.chase.com/"
"loginForms":[{"conjunctionOp":{"conjuctionOp":1}
"componentList":[
{"valueIdentifier":"LOGIN","valueMask":"LOGIN_FIELD","fieldType":{"typeName":"TEXT"},"size":20,"maxlength":32
"name":"LOGIN","displayName":"User ID","isEditable":true,"isOptional":false,"isEscaped":false,"helpText":"4710","isOptionalMFA":false
"isMFA":false},
{"valueIdentifier":"PASSWORD","valueMask":"LOGIN_FIELD","fieldType":{"typeName":"IF_PASSWORD"},"size":20,"maxlength":40
"name":"PASSWORD","displayName":"Password","isEditable":true,"isOptional":false,"isEscaped":false,"helpText":"11976","isOptionalMFA":false
"isMFA":false}
]
"defaultHelpText":"324"}]
"isHeld":false
"isCustom":false
"siteSearchVisibility":true}
```

This should resolve your problem

Regards,

Vishal

Yodlee Team

Answer (score 0):

The flow for updating the credentials is listed in this article [UpdateCredentials Flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Update_Site_Account)

You can follow the exact steps from the article.
Even when the user is associated to a particular site , you can still pull the login form using getSiteLoginForm and show the form to the user to enter the correct credentials and then pass the login form in [updateSiteAccountCredentials](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/updateSiteAccountCredentials) and then proceed with the normal refresh flow.